# How can I prevent duplicate entries on Swift Parse iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I prevent duplicate entry? I'm currently using this code, I got no idea how can i accomplish more.

```
self.applicantClass = PFObject(className: "Applicants")

    self.applicantClass["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
    self.applicantClass["jobId"] = self.object["jobId"] as? String


    self.applicantClass.saveEventually { (success, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            println("saved")
        }else {
            println(error!.userInfo!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to validate using the beforeSave method before sending the data to parse. I don't have the code but a quick search in Google revealed:

https://www.parse.com/questions/unique-fields--2

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't really know anything about Java. :D

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I've accomplished it.

In main.js file:

```
var Applicants = Parse.Object.extend("Applicants");

// Check if jobId is set, and enforce uniqueness based on the jobId column.
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Applicants", function(request, response) {
  if (!request.object.get("jobId")) {
    response.error('A Applicants must have a jobId.');
  } else {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Applicants);
    query.equalTo("jobId", request.object.get("jobId"));
    query.first({
      success: function(object) {
        if (object) {
          response.error("A Applicants with this jobId already exists.");
        } else {
          response.success();
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this Applicants object.");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I don't really think that I need to explain this, code speaks itself. :D have fun.